# How to properly get the Value of a Cookie in PHP?

Tags: php, html, cookies, setcookie

I have code with the following segment in it. This block is actually a debug block used to check before making the script live.

```
if ($_COOKIE['visits'] = '' ) 
{
    $dbgmsg="No cookie found";
    $visits=1;  
    setcookie('visits',$visits,time() + (86400*30)); // 86400 = 1 day 900=15mins    
}
else 
{

    $visits=$_COOKIE['visits'];
    //$dbgmsg="Cookie found. Value is".$_COOKIE['visits'];
    $dbgmsg='<p>Cookie found. Value is'.$_COOKIE["visits"].'</p>';
    $visits++;
    setcookie('visits',$visits,time() + (86400*30));
}
```

When the script runs, the output is: `Cookie found. Value is`

Meaning the value of the cookie is not displayed. Checking the cookie value in Chrome shows that the cookie 'visits' exists, with a value 1. But the code seems to be going into the else block. But the value retrieved is null?

I wish to increment the value of the cookie depending on visits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the assignment `=` operator instead of the comparison `==` operator. That will always be true which is not what you want.

Change

```
if ($_COOKIE['visits'] = '' )
```

to

```
if ($_COOKIE['visits'] == '' )
```

or even better, use `empty()`

```
if (empty($_COOKIE['visits']))
```

Comment: Oops! Not again! Thank you.

Comment: How about trimming it? just a white space in the value of the cookie might throw the validation off, so `if (empty(trim($_COOKIE['visits'])))`

Comment: Not a bad idea. Although since this isn't a user supplied value (obvious tampering aside) it should really be necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't be, but all the aspects should be taken into account. $_COOKIE and $_SESSION can be manipulated by the user at any given time, so it's wise to take an extra precaution